# How to Redirect Affiliate Products on WooCommerce Handpicked Gutenberg Products Block

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm currently working with the WooCommerce Handpicked Products Gutenberg block on my WordPress website. I'm trying to implement functionality where the products displayed in this block, which are affiliate products, redirect users to their respective affiliate URLs when clicked on the product title or image.

I've tried implementing custom code to modify the behavior of the block, but I'm encountering difficulties. Currently, only the button redirects to the affiliate URL. I've been successful in implementing similar functionality on WooCommerce archive pages, but it's not working as expected for the Handpicked Products block when trying to add in the blog posts.

Could someone provide guidance or suggest where I might be going wrong with my implementation?

### Here's a simplified version of what I've attempted so far:

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open');
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 15);

add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_add_aff_link_open', 10);
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_add_aff_link_close', 10);

function woocommerce_add_aff_link_open(){
  $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
  if ($product->is_type('external'))
    echo '<a href="' .
         $product->get_product_url() .
         '" class="wp-block-handpicked-products">';
}

function woocommerce_add_aff_link_close(){
  $product = wc_get_product(get_the_ID());
  if ($product->is_type('external'))
    echo '</a>';
}
```